# Получить массив точек, описывающих геообъект (страна, область, город и etc.)

Tags: google-maps-api, yandex-maps-api, геолокация, geocoding, geo-api

Задача заключается в том, чтобы по наименованию геообъекта получить массив точек, для отрисовки описывающего его полигона.

Предоставляют ли какие-нибудь сервисы такое API?

Comment: Можно использовать Яндекс API, но обратное геокодирование, при получении на вход геокоординаты, возвращает принадлежность геообъекту, а не массив точек, описывающего полигона.

Comment: Может кто знает как из файлов open street map вынуть границы геообъектов?

Answer (score 0):

Возможности получать от API Яндекс.Карт границы уровня меньше, чем [регионы](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/regions-docpage/), нет.

В качестве решения вы можете получать или скачивать контуры интересующих вас границ на сторонних сервисах, например http://data.esosedi.org/ , в формате geoJSON и отображать их любыми удобными вам инструментами Яндекса, Гугла или других геосервисов.